# PHP / MySQL long date format query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a PHP import task that imports around 130,000 rows of class attendance data, with the date field coming along in `DD LM YYYY` format - E.g. 16 September 2013.

I perform a task to update the format of the date field to `YYYY-MM-DD` and then delete any records that are greater than the current date:

```
$todaysdate =  date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "DELETE from tbl_data_attendance WHERE date > '$todaysdate'"; if(!mysql_query($sql)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}
```

Any ideas how I could perform the deletion of future records before the date update?
E.g. Delete > 16 September 2013.
This would prevent wasting time updating rows that are only going to end up being deleted.

Thanks in advance!

**Further info:**

CSV file structure and example data:
"Adno","Mark","Date","Class","Subject","Teacher","Room","Recorded By"

"123456","Y","17 September 2013","13A/Hi3","History","Mr John Smith","X6"

To load the CSV file into the table I'm using the following:

```
$importquery = mysql_query('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$today.' - Report - Attendance Data.csv" INTO TABLE tbl_data_attendance FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" IGNORE 1 LINES')or die(mysql_error());
```

All I am trying to work out is if it is possible to delete any records greater than today whilst the date format is still set to "17 September 2012", rather than updating the date field to 2013-09-17 and then running the delete query shown above.

Comment: When you do the conversion, check to see if the date is in the future. If it is, just don't put it in the database.

Comment: It's not quite clear whether you have the records in DB already, or you still in process of importing them. For the latter, it's rather trivial to extract the real date using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: I think you need to learn about before insert/ before update triggers (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).  These are how constraints are implemented in MySQL.

Comment: The records are already loaded into the database, using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to import the 12mb attendance CSV report...

What I want to do is delete any records greater than the current date before performing the date format update.

For example: Import runs, loads 130,000 rows, delete > 16 September 2013, reduced to 6000 rows of data, then update date format to 2013-09-16, 2013-09-15 etc. etc.

Comment: `DELETE from tbl_data_attendance WHERE date > NOW()`

Comment: Can you show what your file and table schema look like? You can probably do it all while importing your data with `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: @Shaun: you will have to update records to YYYY-MM-DD date format first, and then the delete query is trivial.